# DIV Background with ASP.NET Gridview of unknown height

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a two DIV's, both are floating, one on the left, one on the right, they are both nested within another DIV (parent) which centers both.  The floating left/right DIV's have ASP.NET Gridviews of unknown number of records.  Therefore the vertical height is unknown.  Does anyone, have suggestions to address the background color of the parent DIV?  The entire page is wrapped in a master page which does not have the white background.

Comment: Not sure what you mean address the background colour? can you not just set it?

Comment: The parent DIV has a background color specified (white), while the master page has a  background color of rust/red but because the height is unknown, even though it is set at 100% doesn't render.  If I change the parent DIV to be X-pixels in height, the color then renders but it's not dynamic matching the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your parent div to have bottom:0, top:0. position it as absolute (if possible). That way it would fill its parent and render as white=> which I think is what you want?